# Threading fails on pc with security tool installed

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a wpf applications which on a few pcs works great.
However, on one pc it doesn't, and that pc has `Fortres 101` installed.

The code that crashes is here:

```
public void OpenLoadingWindowInNewThread(int width, int height, int top)
    {
        thread = new Thread(x => OpenLoadingWindow(width, height, top));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }
```

`OpenLoadingWindowInNewThread()` is called, and `OpenLoadingWindow()` isn't called, so the line that throws the exception is this one:

```
thread = new Thread(x => OpenLoadingWindow(width, height, top));
```

Here is the stack:

> at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

How can I fix this?

The exception is:

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`

Comment: You've posted the stacktrace but without the error message and type of the exception which are very important.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. I updated the question, sorry.

Comment: Catch the exception and refer to its `InnerException` property and update your question please.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that it's the thread that can't be launched. Wrap the `OpenLoadingWindow` call in a try/catch.

Comment: Are you calling OpenLoadingWindowInNewThread method in a loop?

Comment: Security tools do not affect .NET threading. Most likely you have a threading bug that happened to appear on that specific PC. Why are you trying to open a window in a different thread anyway? There are a lot of options for performing work on the background, or displaying a lot of data on the UI and *none* of them require a different UI thread

Comment: @KarthikAMR In a method, not in a loop.

Comment: @petko_stankoski The call stack you posted shows that the exception happened in your application's constructor, not in the code you posted. Please post the *entire* exception - message, full call stack and inner exceptions. You can get this easily by calling `Exception.ToString()`.